# Using ImageMagick to generate thumbnails for images stored in Amazon S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm looking to use ImageMagick's convert utility to make thumbnails for images stored in S3. I'm writing this in Python.

How should I approach this?

Should I read the image from S3, save it to a temporary folder on an EC2 instance, generate the thumbnail to a temporary directory, then put the temporary file into S3 and delete it?

Or can I "pipe" the result from S3 right into ImageMagick without storing it to local disk?

Is there a recommended way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subprocess with file objects and directly pipe them to imagemagick.
For example here I convert directly an online png to a jpg without using temporary files.

```
import subprocess
import urllib2
import sys 
source = urllib2.urlopen('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png')
p = subprocess.Popen(['convert','png:-', 'jpg:-'], stdin=source, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()[0] # this is your converted image
```

Comment: Will this use a lot of memory?

Comment: If you pipe the process out to another descriptor, the memory usage should be minimal: only the convert process buffers which I completely guess depending on its implementation but should be once the size of the decompressed image + the size of the decompressed thumbnail. If they have done better than that they have a really good internal implementation ;)

Comment: Thanks. How could I extend this to generate multiple thumbnail sizes? If I put in another subprocess.Popen(...) line with different dimensions, would it re-download the entire full image from S3?

Comment: Every other time I execute the above code, I get the following error: convert: improper image header `-' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3246.
convert: missing an image filename `jpg:-' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3011.